# 'Closest Healing' or another phrase for a book title?

Tags: meaning, nuance

I have written a book and will publish it.

I have suffered a lot from a disease over a decade, but after I prayed to God in fasting I found its healing was very close, not far from me.

Therefore, I am going to publish the book to help patients not to be suffered as me but to find true healing that is nearby.

I just can consider its title such as "The Closest Healing" or "The Nearest Healing."
I neither know what others are available nor know which is better among the two above.
As English is my second language, I cannot figure out their nuances.
Which one is better, or other word?

I like to use Healing than cure or remedy as its concept contains Whole Person Healing.

Please help me to find out a good English title.
Thank you.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) or [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com) stackexchanges more useful for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'close/near' healing in the first place. Are you saying that (1) You were healed after 10 years 2 months; (2) You received an obvious partial healing after 10 years; (3) After 10 years you were absolutely convinced that you would be fully healed within the next 6 months say ... ? There are big differences.

Comment: I might recommend "Healing is Nearby" or "Healing is Closer Than You Think".

Comment: Thanks, jwpat7! I will try to post in those two stackexchanges.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. My case is (3). After a decade, God revealed me the cause and the way to be healed and I was convinced that I would be healed and it became true.

Comment: Thanks, GEdgar, for your reply. I prefer to have a name that doesn't have verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut my opinion, but although the two words "closest" and "nearest" are essentially synonyms, to me "closest" seems to connote something that is even closer than near, and could easily be understood as "inside".

I cannot give you a nicely logical answer, but "The Closest Healing" seems better than "Nearest".

On the other hand, another similar title comes to mind: "The Healing From Within".

Your project sounds interesting - do you have a publisher already?  And is this a translation into English from your first language, or is it written originally in English?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's the first one of a series of three books. Considering 2nd and 3rd ones titles are relatively easier for me such as "The Easiest Healing" and "The Most Amazing Healing." I will publish these books in eBook and the first one that I completed will be free. My plan is publishing the first two books first and I will translate them and publish in English. These books come from not only my experience but also from my doctoral dissertation study in US. It is my life time project. I came from South Korea, but I studied master and doctoral in US and worked in both countries.

Comment: @Jung - Maybe after you've completed your second installment, you can ask another question about "Easiest" vs. "Simplest".

Comment: @J.R. - Snidely done, sir (or madam)!

Comment: Thanks, J.R., for your comment. You're right. I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: @J.R.: Did Jung just take your comment seriously?  I believe he did!  And I am not sure how to react to that.  Although I am near to laughing my ahem off.

Answer (score 0):

consider: "Your Healing is Just [Around The Corner](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/around+the+corner)" or "Healing - Just [Around the Corner](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/around+the+corner)"

> On the other side of a street corner, as in The doctor's office is
>   around the corner from our house . [First half of 1800s]
>
> Nearby, a short distance away, as in The nearest grocery store is just
>   around the corner . [Early 1800s]
>
> Very soon, imminent, as in You never know what stroke of luck lies
>   just around the corner . [First half of 1900s]

If you want just one word to replace "closest" or "nearest" then try "[imminent](https://www.wordnik.com/words/imminent)" (as in "Imminent Healing"

> adj. About to occur; impending: in imminent danger.

The word "impending" can also work (as in "Impending Healing")

> adj. Approaching; drawing near; about to happen

to make it more personal, I suggest you use "Your Imminent Healing" or "Your Impending Healing"

Comment: Thanks, Paul! I like to have a short name as much as possible. Also, like to have a easy one. I have considered "The Closest Healing" or "The Nearest Healing" only. With the hints of the answers, I became to consider "The Healing Closest" or "The Healing Nearest." What do you think about them?

Comment: @Jung try "The Healing Near You" or "The Healing Nearby". "Imminent Healing" or "Impending Healing" also works as it has the sense that healing is really about to happen.